# Failure to install Chocolatey (while trying to do full Install of NativeScript on Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, nativescript, failed-installation

I can not do a full setup of NativeScript on my Windows 10 computer. I am following the instructions on:

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win

As instructed on the above link, I am trying to run the following command from a cmd window (running as administrator):

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

But nothing happens.

I have `Node v12.18.3` installed on my computer.